# Posting every 90 minutes bug

Tags: bug

Here's something I realized recently. If your post has a certain error (eg: duplicate title) and you click the post button, Stack Overflow detects it as a submission.

This means scrolling back up and fixing the title and then pressing the submit again will display the error `you can only submit once every 90 minutes.`

I have not tried this out in other sites on the SE.

Update: After trying several times repeatedly, I was able to post it after 10 mins from the original time.

Comment: Why not post it in MSO then?

Comment: This sounds unlikely. Are you sure you haven't just submitted a previous question within 90 minutes, and all that was actually happening in your scenario is that the first submission attempt triggered the validation, and then on successful validation it checked the previous post time and found the earlier question?

Comment: @ShadowWizard What is that?

Comment: @John http://meta.stackoverflow.com/, the meta site for Stack Overflow where you report Stack Overflow bugs.

Comment: @JonW Yes I'm sure. I do not share accounts and this is my first question in about a week.I tried reloading the page and resubmitting but it failed. Got through at about the 10 minute mark. Maybe the counter cleared at that point.

Comment: Also, I see [you posted the question just fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605485/mysql-prepared-statement-not-working) - so not sure what bug you report.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, I mentioned it in the *update*.

Comment: Cross-site dupe of [Error -- "you can only post once every 90 minutes" but I haven't posted in days](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259941)

Comment: Anyway, more likely the issue is someone sharing your IP posted 80 minutes before you.

Comment: And here it is just a duplicate of [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899)

Comment: I am at work so yes, I guess that is possible.